# Default Downloads Directory for Firefox 26

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I used below code to get Default Downloads Directory for Firefox 25 and below:

```
var defaultDownloadsDirectory = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/download-manager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIDownloadManager).defaultDownloadsDirectory;
```

Although it works fine for Firefox  26, it is recommended not to use nsIDownloadManager anymore.
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDownloadManager)

How can I get default Downloads Directory for Firefox 26 and above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the above code will still work for the time being...

As I had to update the stuff myself recently, here is the code I came up with. It is backward-compatible.

```
const getDefaultDownloadsDirectory = (function() {
  function oldFallback(callback) {
    let dlm = Cc["@mozilla.org/download-manager;1"].getService(Ci.nsIDownloadManager);
    var dir;
    try {
      dir = dlm.userDownloadsDirectory;
    }
    catch (ex) {
      dir = dlm.defaultDownloadsDirectory;
    }
    callback(dir.path);
  }

  try {
    let Downloads = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm", {}).Downloads;
    if (!Downloads.getPreferredDownloadsDirectory) {
      throw new Error("not supported");
    }
    return function newDownloads(callback) {
      var p = Downloads.getPreferredDownloadsDirectory();
      if (!p) {
        oldFallback(callback);
        return;
      }
      p.then(function success(r) {
        callback(r);
      }, function fail(e) {
        oldFallback(callback);
      });
    };
  }
  catch (ex) {
    return oldFallback;
  }
})();
```

Yeah, that is quite nasty.
The short way, without error handling, would be:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm");
Downloads.getPreferredDownloadsDirectory().then(function(result) {
  // do something with |result|
});
```

Please note that this new API is async. There is no synchronous variant.